# Creating view in Android

Tags: android, view, android-context

I have what should be a simple problem but I'm struggling to see my error. I'm trying to create a new instance of a custom view and set the image of the contained ImageView. But I get errors.

I'm getting errors in the following method. It says

**"The constructor ImagePreviewView(CreateNewActivity) is undefined"**, on the first line (this refering to an Activity). I've tried `this.getApplicationContext` and `this.getBaseContext` and neither has worked.

On the second line it says: **"The method setImage(Bitmap) is undefined for the type ImagePreviewView"**, when there is obviously a method that matches. The weird thing is the errors go away when I retype the code, but come back again when I save.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private void AddNewAfterSelection(Pic pic){
    ImagePreviewView ipView = new ImagePreviewView(this);
    ipView.setImage(pic.getImage());
}
```

The constructor and setImage method:

```
public ImagePreviewView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_image_preview,null));
    
    imageView = (ResizingImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
    btnUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
    btnDown = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDown);
    btnRemove = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
}

public void setImage(Bitmap b){
    imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

EDIT:  I made the changes Piyush Gupta suggested and I'm still getting the same errors. Anything else I should try?

Comment: What does ImagePreviewView extend from?

Comment: ImagePreviewView extends RelativeLayout

Comment: And what does CreateNewActivity extend from? FragmentActivity or Activity?

Comment: CreateNewActivity extends from Activity